# Squid Proxy Setup, Paired With Google Cloud - Configure Outgoing Traffic

Tags: squid, port-forwarding, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

Summary;

I am attempting to set up a transparent proxy for use with a Minecraft server I'm setting up for friends at home. I am needing help figuring out the more technical aspects of setting up Squid to forward to my home network, with a specified interface (25565).

---

**Details:**

**1 -** I'm using Ubuntu-1804.

....**1.A -** I've decided on, and installed, Squid for my proxy.

....**1.B -** I've set the flag `tcp_outgoing_address` to my public IP, **but unsure of how to set what port to use for outgoing traffic/traffic going to my IP.** I have also set `http_port` to 25565, though my understanding is that this is what the proxy will listen on.

**2 -**  I've configured an inbound firewall rule in Google cloud to allow traffic coming in on port 25565. Not sure if there's anything else I need to set for this. "Targets" is set to "Apply to all".

---

---

I've never worked with Squid or Google Cloud platform in earnest before, so this is all new to me. Thank you in advance for any assistance provided. If you need additional information, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm) on the Google Cloud on how to configure a proxy.
There are the details to forward requests from the outside to instances inside the GCP.

As you want to forward them to your home network, you will need to adapt it. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/a67hly/squid_proxy_a_short_guide_forward_transparent/) is a good guide for a forward proxy.

You can also set up the Minecraft [server on the GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server).